# Design an FIR linear phase lowpass filter using windows to meet the following specifications. What is given in the question? How to start solving it?

Tags: filters, filter-design, lowpass-filter, digital-filters, filtering

[image]
[image]
[image]
What is given in this question? I have not seen a single solution of these types of filter design problems in the internet. So I am confused, how do I proceed solving these problems. Can you guide me a bit?

Comment: "I have not seen a single solution of these types of filter design problems in the internet." Maybe get yourself a proper textbook?

Comment: Solution is not there in any textbook I am following.

Comment: I'd suggest to stop looking for the solution and rather learn what you need to solve it on your own.

Comment: I solved the first two questions. But confused on the 3rd one.